# Adding a dash between 2 even numbers after printing out randomly generated numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, for-loop

So I've been trying to add a dash between every even number, but it's not outputting the dash. What am I doing wrong?

Generating 20 random numbers and putting them into array

```
var i = 0;
mainarr = [];

do {
    mainarr[i]=parseInt(Math.random()*10);
    i++;
}
while (i<20);
```

Printing the 20 numbers and adding dashes between every even number

```
var endVal =20;
for (i=0; i< endVal ;)
{
    main.innerHTML += mainarr[i];

        if ((i%2)==0) {
            i++;
            if ((i % 2)==0)
                main.innerHTML += "-";
        }
        else
            i++;
}
```

Comment: You're basically saying in your loop "if `i` is even, increment it, and if it's even again, then add the dash". If `i` is even, `i+1` cannot be even...

Comment: Ah I get what you're saying.. so I go  i -1 so I can go back and add the hyphen.

The hyphen wouldnt even show when I ran the script anyways though

Comment: never *ever* use `+=` style operations on `innerHTML` - every operation will require the browser to serialise the given element's contents, then you update the string, and then put it back into the DOM again!

Comment: just lose the second `if((i % 2)==0)` statement (you already checked if it is even..)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it, using a temporary variable to store whether or not the last value was even, and comparing it against the current value.

```
var length = mainarr.length,
    lastNumberEven = false,
    thisNumberEven,
    tmpString = '';
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if ((thisNumberEven = mainarr[i] % 2 == 0) && lastNumberEven) {
        tmpString += '-';
    }
    tmpString += mainarr[i];
    lastNumberEven = thisNumberEven;
}
main.innerHTML = tmpString;
```

Comment: Haha, poorly asked question, since he wasn't meaning a even index, but a even value. +1